# Magento 2 cant override the minicart.html file using html

Tags: overrides, magento2.2.6, mini-cart

I am going to override the minicart.html file using knockout for my custom code as below at the default file location is :

```
/var/www/html/magento226/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

***code***

```
<!-- ko if: customracking.length -->
            <div class="product customracking" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko text: 'Custom Racking Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko text: 'Custom Racking Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product customracking list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: customracking as: 'custom' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: custom.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(custom.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: custom.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(custom.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: custom.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

Can anybody let me know how to solve this?

If anyone know, please let me help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to minicart file override in your custom theme

Comment: minicart.phtml? you want to say ? but minicart is rendering using the knockout i want to overrirte the knockout rendering template file.then how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***override in theme file location :***

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

***After changes in default.html file, we have to deploy static file using command,***

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i already overrite thay file but it will not reflacted even this                     <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko text: 'Custom Racking Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
ko text also not rendering

i also cache clean setup upgrade and the deploy command run

Comment: @kinjalmehta Please verify file path Magento_Checkout/web/template/ or  Magento_Checkout/template/ ?

Comment: it's a Magento_Checkout/web/template/

Comment: @kinjalmehta You have to delete default.html file from => pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item and reload page again.

Comment: i do done that command but i face the error like : Bindings value: foreach: { data: customracking as: 'custom' }

Comment: error means changes are applied

Comment: yes changes is now applied but now i face the error and i overrite the file : Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem.php and add the function as below : 

/**
     * get custom-racking
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomRacking()
    {
        return array('customracking'=>array('label'=>'test','value'=>'abc','label'=>"hello","value"=>"text"));
    }

but this array did not consume as a foreach in knockout

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for the error : customracking.lengh can not bind using knockout so i update the function in the file :

> Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem.php

```
protected function getCustomRacking()
    {
        $data = array('0'=>array('label'=>'test','value'=>'123'),'1'=>array('label'=>'hello','value'=>'456'));
        return $data;
    }
```

but this array did not consume as a foreach in knockout now the magento will rendor the custom array in html file using knockout in minicart same as product option render.